# Make hudson automatically show pom description in its project page

Tags: maven-2, hudson

I use Hudson to do continuous integration on some maven projects. For these projects, I would like to have the pom description used as content for the Hudson job description. is there a solution to automatically have this configured ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a bit hard to do because Hudson needs the config so it can checkout the POM. What you can try is use the command line API to configure the project.

Another solution is to run `mvn install site`. That will generate the web site for the project and Hudson will present a link to it right below the description, so you can use this description:

```
This is a Maven project; click the link below to visit the web site.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just run mvn site no mvn install needed to see the link about the generated site in Hudson.